# Big O notation for Array/Stack/Queue

Tags: java, arrays, stack, queue, big-o

I am wondering, why Big O notation is O(1) for Array/Stack/Queue in avg. cases when we are inserting and deleting an element ?

In my understanding, it is O(1) because interting and deleting an element takes a constant amount of time no matter the amount of data in the set but I am still little bit confused. Any help will be highly appreciated in removing my confusion.

Comment: What are you confused with?

Comment: @kennytm When we are inserting and deleting an element in Array/Stack/Queue in avg cases, why Big O notation is O(1) why not O(n) ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307787/what-does-wikipedia-mean-when-it-says-the-complexity-of-inserting-an-item-at-the

Comment: It is at least unclear what the author of this question meant by "insert" (particularly in reference to the 3 different data structures at once), if not this also being a duplicate of multiple other questions.  Unfortunately it appears they are no longer registered.  I think this should be closed for all these reasons.

Answer (score 1):

*O(1)* - notation means that the operation is performed in constant time.

*O(n)* - notation means the operation is performed in linear time, e.g. traversing a list.

#### Array

We start with the most obvious one. Array *A* has a fixed length *n*, and its elements can be accessed in constant time, by addressing the appropriate location in memory, i.e.

```
A[i]=10;
```

#### Stack

Stack is a Last in first out data structure. We always have a pointer/reference to the top element. So, even if the stack is implemented as a list, where we cannot address a specific element in it in constant time (we have to traverse the list in *O(n)*), we are accessing the topmost element with pop/peak, to which we have a pointer/reference and is thus accessible in constant time *O(1)*.

```
Stack.pop(); //or peak() perhaps
```

#### Queue

Queue is a first in first out data structure. As with stack, accessing a specific element of the Queue can be done in linear time *O(n)*, as we need to traverse it. But we usually have a pointer/reference to the first and last element of the queue. Therefore both enqueue and dequeue can be performed in constant time *O(1)*.

Comment: As per my understanding, the Big-O notation is O(1) in array/stack/queue in avg. cases because inserting and deleting an element gonna takes 1 step regardless of the size of the array. For Searching an element, the  big-o notation is O(n) because sometimes the element we are searching is the 1st element or middle element or the last element of an array. Let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: I was going through this ( https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/4874OS_Appendix_Big_O_Cheat_Sheet.pdf ) cheat sheet, my question is why there is no best cases here for Array/Stack/Queue, LinkedList, Doubly Linked List, Hash Table and Binary Search Tree ?

Comment: Why have they specified only avg. cases and worst cases ? Why not best cases ?

Answer (score 0):

For array based stacks, all operations are O(1) because you can only delete the item on top of the stack (you dont have to loop or iterate or do anything else). To insert is the same.
For linked based stacks, they are also all O(1) except the destructor since you have to loop over the nodes and delete each one.
For array-based ques, I am only sure that deque is O(N) since you return the first item and then you would move front.

I recommend watching [this guy's videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okr-XE8yTO8&t=35s), where he explains all of those in depth. Good luck!